# Is it possible to manipulate the operating system (Windows) with java?

Tags: java, windows, user-interface

Is it possible to manipulate the operating system with java? I wanted to build a program that manipulates the operating system by creating keys in the windows registry, observes the behavior of the hardware (like a task manager)

Comment: Did you try to search for something like "Java create registry keys"? That would spare you the question.

Comment: This is not exactly my doubt, I wanted to know if it is possible without the help of other languages, or if there is a better one.

Comment: Java isn't great for writing to the native operating system. Java shines for cross-platform functionality, but not for anything specific to one OS. It's definitely possible through JNI libraries, but it won't be as easy as other languages like C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible call native code to perform OS specific calls from Java - such as manipulate the Windows Registry. You should look at JNI - such as this [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/jni), or if you use JDK16 or JDK17 you might have a look at the incubating [JDK Panama - Foreign Memory API](https://jdk.java.net/panama/).

However be warned that Panama APIs may change by the time (/whenever) they are incorporated into JDK officially. Also the JDK17 version is different to JDK16, and the tools support that makes Panama so easy to use - `jextract` - was not released with JDK16 or JDK17 and you may want to view the latest Panama Early Access build instead. This answer has example of native calls using [JDK17 Panama](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69321128/how-to-call-a-c-function-from-java-17-using-jep-412-foreign-function-memory-a/69347525#69347525).

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, Java it's not a language for low-level tasks.
Therefore, you can implement some method natively (with **C**) using the **native** keyword and the **Java Native Interface** (**JNI**).
However, the Java API is huge, so you should see the official documentation.
You should try **Rust** instead.